# pygtk - update a gtk.liststore adds blank line

Tags: python, pygtk

I'm having issue with adding extra lines to gtk.liststore. below is a snipped of the code. The glade definition can be found [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/829293/mainwindow.glade).  When I add a row the row seperators appear but where text should appear i keeps empty... please help define everything with glade interface designer.

```
class GTKInterface(gobject.GObject):
 __gsignals__ = {

 }
 def __init__(self):
  gobject.GObject.__init__(self)
  self.gladefile = 'glade/mainwindow.glade'
  self.builder = gtk.Builder()
  self.builder.add_from_file(self.gladefile)
  self.treeview = self.builder.get_object('treeview1')
  self.liststore = self.builder.get_object('liststore')

def add_row(self, episodes):
  for ep in episodes:
   self.liststore.append(["test","test1", "test2"])
```

What did I miss or how can this be solved?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I have found what I have forgot cell renders !!! I read about [here](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/ch-TreeViewWidget.html)